# Implementing my own code to handle "*" and / or "**" on a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know what `*` and `**` do in Python (e.g. [What do the * (star) and ** (double star) operators mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-do-the-star-and-double-star-operators-mean-in-a-function-call)).  But if I want to create my own "dict-like" class.  I'm wondering if `**` maps to some dunder method that I can add to my class such that my class can respond to `**` in a similar way.  If not a dunder, is there some other way to create a fully dict-like class that *does* support a `**` prefix operator?

(Bonus points for the same on a tuple-like class for `*`, but it's the dict version I need a solution to!)

Comment: For `*` unpacking the class must be iterable, defining a `__iter__` method. For `**` keyword unpacking, it must adhere to a dict interface. One way is to extend `collections.abc.Mapping`

Comment: As far as I can find, unpacking doesn't correspond to any dunder methods. But you can subclass from dict, or even better, from UserDict in collections, to get the mapping functionality.

Comment: The question is a slighlty different question, but the answer is definitely in the "dupe" question.  Not deleting as this may still be useful to navigate to the answer - very hard searching on `*` and `**`!